# How to compile 64bit asp.net web site with visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, 64-bit

How can I make Visual Studio to use the 64bit compiler (csc.exe/vbc.exe) for an Asp.Net web site?

Comment: You just do it? There's nothing special that you need to do... are you talking about the built-in web server, perhaps, that's a 32-bit executable?

Comment: No, I'm talking about simple compilation of Visual Studio 2008 to an IIS web application. I can see it uses the x86 compilers, thus generating platform related errors upon compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apparently you can't.** x86 compilation will occur with VS 2008 and x64/x86 compilation will occur with your IIS (depending on your window's platform). You can't change it even by using the compilation parameters at the web.config - an error will occur.