# Using 64-bit references in ASP.NET Web Site Project - design time issues

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, vs-web-site-project, aspnet-compiler

**Background:** We have old-style ASP.NET WSP - web site project. This is the one that does not produces single DLL and uses `dll.refresh` files for reference mappings.

**Problem:** Using VS2017, we're able to work with it with no issues but only as long as DLLs we reference are not x64. See pictures below

*With x64 DLLs*
[image: When x64 DLLs are in reference, the reference is NOT listed]

*With x86 DLLs*
[image: When x86 DLLs are in reference, the reference IS listed]

As result, in code files we get suggestions to "add reference". This type of "project" is regulated in large by `web.config`. But I couldn't find any switch that would help. I also turned on "Use 64-bit IIS" in tools but no help.

**What do we know**

- This is a design time issue
- If I use `Aspnet_compiler` against this WSP with x64 dependencies, it compiles fine
- On Dev box I can use x86 dependencies and work in this way (and have been for 18 years). But on build box we need x64 DLLs.
  **++** This one demands explanation. We used to only precompile (aspnet_compiler) for release. But now, we also want to build and validate before precompilation. Precompilation without validation has couple drawbacks - it doesn't validate `ashx` handlers and it doesn't pull dependencies - we have to know which DLLs to supply and then it will compile.

It seem to me that somehow I need to tell Visual Studio to use 64-bit tools, but I don't know how. For projects with project files there is `<AspNetToolPath>` tag. But how to replicate this here? When I build with MSBUILD it gives me `ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly... incorrect format`. So, there is something with wrong toolset and in VS background compilation is not working. And same with MSBuild - it picks wrong toolset, or, it picks whatever toolset is should but I need to give command which to use.

Comment: Is this really the answer? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950664/1704458

Comment: Have you ever got this working? I've ran into the exact same problem where I want to use a 64bit DLL in an old Web Site Project :(

Comment: @Landcross Thank you for reminding this to me. Yes! I had communication with Microsoft specialists and they gave me the answer I just posted below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is official answer I've got from Microsoft**

...unfortunately **Visual Studio does not have good support for 64 bit assemblies for website projects**. In general, this is because Visual Studio and an external process used for Asp.Net intellisense are 32bit applications and thus cannot load these assemblies. However, since this is a website the build will happen on the server when the page is requested. Because of this, and in general to improve the F5 inner-loop, you can turn off the build in VS - it is only used for validation purposes anyway. To do this:

- right-click on *Project* node and choose *Property Pages*
- On the *Build* tab change the *Before running startup* page option to *"No build"*, and uncheck the *Build web site* as part of solution

Doing this means **you will not see build errors in the IDE**, instead **they will appear in the browser when you browse to the affected page**. And **intellisense will not be accurate** since types from the 64 bit assemblies will not be recognized.

Comment: That's a bummer :( That doesn't sound like an ideal solution. In any case, thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: @Landcross The "ideal" solution that we use:  we use x86 and AnyCpu third party components during design/debug time. We precompile our website using x64 (this is optional but lets you verify integrity during build time). + precompile means faster loads on deployment servers. Generally, we're trying to have all components AnyCpu but some third parties provide only x86/x64, which might change soon

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable when 32 and 64 bit dll files are available. The thing is, I want/need to use a third-party package that (nowadays) only provides a 64 bit version...

Comment: @Landcross wow! this is horrible. Can you contact them and ask for AnyCPU version ? If there is really not a lot in it, you can reflect and build your own version, or create wrappers

Comment: It's the open-source Google OR tools, I don't think they'll be releasing a 32 bit version anymore since as far as I understand it they deprecated that a while ago. Maybe I can build a 32 bit version myself from source, but not sure if that'll work, haven't tried that yet. It doesn't help that I'm not that experienced with .NET (and the last time I used it was a few years ago) haha.

Comment: This **solution** might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30851524/9258504

Comment: @SamBerk You're mixing design time and runtime